# Country I've only been in for a while won't give me a police clearance certificate - what can I do about it?

Tags: immigration, canada

I am going through a process to get a work permit for Canada, and I have been advised to get police clearance certificates for all countries where I've spent more than six months in the last few years.

I have spent close to six months in Chile, total, but not in a row. I am from Brazil, so I do not need a passport nor a visa to get into Chile - I can travel there with just my brazilian ID. I did get stamps on my passport for every time I went in and out of Chile, though, because I thought it would be nice to have.

Now my advisors are saying I should get a police clearance certificate from Chile because of that.

**I know how to get one. But Chile will not provide me with such a certificate because I do not have a chilean ID (called a RUT).** I never needed a chilean ID because everywhere I went accepted my brazilian ID.

In order to get a Chilean ID, I would need to get a chilean visa, move there, get a job in a local company, and spend at least five months there (best case scenario), but I have seen people taking up to a year to get a chilean ID. So it does not seem feasible at all.

Can this be a problem when it comes to getting a work permit to Canada, and what can I do about it?

Comment: Can you avoid going over 6 months in Chili until after you have your work permit?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan too ñate, I have been there last year.

Comment: It's probably easier to replace your passport and then avoid mentioning it on the visa application.

Comment: And when the work permit application or the Canadian immigration officer asks where the OP has been spending his time...then what?

Comment: Which programme are you applying to? Are you sure the requirement isn’t just for countries where you’ve spent 6 months or more in a row? Express Entry and IEC both state this eg  https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/apply-permanent-residence/police-certificates.html

Comment: @traveller IEC.

Answer (score 4):

First, try to find out whether you indeed will need a police certificate. [Guide for work permit application](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/guide-5487-applying-work-permit-outside-canada.html) including [special instructions for Brazil](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM5929E.pdf) don't say police certificates are absolute requirement but simply that they may ask for them if needed. That said, it is possible that you are getting the certificate just in case it is requested, and therefore you can safe time.

Indeed [the process to get police certificate from Chile requires RUT or RUN](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/medical-police/police-certificates/how/chile.html). If you do get asked for it, this is what you can do: write down any step of the process of requesting for police certificate, if possible do the process using letters instead of talking in person. If you do need to talk in person, bring a witness. Both you and the witness should write down the conversation as soon as possible. Make sure to follow any reasonable instructions from Chile authority trying to get the certificate. If you follow all reasonable instruction and still cannot get the police certificate, submit copies of all letters and notes especially the reason of failure in place of the certificate.

Comment: Yes, official documentation that Chile refused to provide a certificate is a strong indication that you tried to get one and that you expected it to be clean.